# Checking SVN repository into new server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

We have been using [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) along with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) for a while now. One of PC Techs here accidentally erased the server containing VisualSVN Server on it. Fortunately, I had done a get latest the night before and I have all the repositories on my local machine.

I reinstalled Windows Server back on the machine and reinstalled VisualSVN. My question is, using TortoiseSVN, is there a way to "check in" my repositories on my local machine back onto VisualSVN? Or do I need to manually go through and create each individual repository and check in each project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First order of business, revoke that PC Tech's privileges on the network. Grant him no more access than the receptionist in the lobby has, because clearly he's not responsible enough to have the rights that he has.

Second order of business, get your whole environment locked down. Stuff like this should **never** happen in a mature professional environment. Today it's the VisualSVN server. Will your domain controller be next? Or the intranet?

> Fortunately, I had done a get latest the night before and I have all the repositories on my local machine.

No you don't. You have a copy of the latest revision of the repository in **working copies** on your local machine.

> Is there a way to "check in" my repositories on my local machine back onto VisualSVN.

You don't have repositories, you have working copies. They are linked to the repositories you checked them out from. It is not possible to create a new repository and commit that working copy back to it - the best you can do is export the contents of the working copy, then import into a new repository.

Revision history is not kept in Subversion working copies (unlike Mercurial or git), so all of that is lost.

Restore the erased server and its data from backups (you may have to do some gymnastics to get back in business, and you might lost a few revisions of history, but you'll at least have most of it). You do have recent and usable backups, right?

If you don't have a backup, you're SOL. All you have is the current version of the projects that you have in your local working copies. You'll have to start over with an empty repository, import what you have on your local machine, and press forward.